# Fixed background regardless of browser position (explanation picture included!)

Tags: javascript, html, css

If possible I would prefer to do this in HTML/CSS/JS but if not, anything goes.

I'm trying to set the background for a webpage to have a kind of absolute position that will remain there regardless of where the browser window is on the screen and regardless of size.

Picture for clarification:

[image]

(Explaination for picture: Red outline is browser window, the light blue-transparent picture is the position and size that the picture should always have)

Comment: I'm thinking you can't? You can get the screen size and the window size, but I don't think you can get the browser window offset relative to the screen, so there's no way to know where the browser is ?

Comment: @adeneo I think most browsers give you `window.screenX` and `screenY`.

Comment: @Pointy - That's pretty cool, I knew about those but never found them useful for anything, I guess this is it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the screen position of the window with `window.screenX` and `window.screenY`.  Then you can track that with a simple interval timer:

```
setInterval(function() {
  $('body').css('backgroundPosition',
              -window.screenX + 'px ' + -window.screenY + 'px');
}, 50);
```

(That uses jQuery but it's not necessary.)

[Here is a jsbin to demonstrate.](http://jsbin.com/oDadOvo/1) It's a little jumpy, but it'll probably heat up client machines as it stands so I wouldn't run the timer too much faster. The problem is that while the browser will tell you about window size changes (the "resize" event), it won't tell you via events about the window being moved around.

Here's a somewhat more efficient version without jQuery and with some checks to avoid touching the style when the window hasn't moved. [This doesn't seem to make Firefox or Chrome go too nuts](http://jsbin.com/oDadOvo/3) even running every 15 milliseconds:

```
(function() {
  var sx = window.screenX, sy = window.screenY;

  setInterval(function() {
    if (window.screenX !== sx || window.screenY !== sy)
      document.body.style.backgroundPosition = 
         -(sx = window.screenX) + 'px ' + -(sy = window.screenY) + 'px';
  }, 15);
})()
```

Comment: thats a nice hack. The problem i see is jquery's css is really slow. native javascript will improve it a lot.

Comment: @Prongs yes that may be so - I'll tinker with the jsbin and see.

Comment: @Prongs [well it doesn't make much of a visible difference in Firefox at least.](http://jsbin.com/oDadOvo/2)

Comment: Thanks Pointy it works great! I lowered the update frequency to 5ms, but I assume that should be fine since it's not a public website so only one person at a time will access it.
One question though - I'm trying to line it up with my desktop background, and it seems like the background on the website is ~150 pixels or so too much towards the bottom. How can I change the offset to correct this?

Comment: As regards to my offset question, I'm using the last edit you made (http://jsbin.com/oDadOvo/2/edit)

Comment: @user3163104 hmm ... well that may depend a little on how the browser reports "screenX" and "screenY".  I'll play around and see if I can tell what Firefox is doing. It may not be exactly the same for all browsers, unfortunately.

Comment: It seems to be dependant of the UI-size of the browser, and if the ui part of the browser is moved offscreen towards the top, it will break the background there. In other words the offset is as high as the browserui is.
I really only need it to work for firefox, so if this is impossible to solve, a specific number of pixel-offset would work aswell.

Comment: @user3163104 Firefox on Linux seems to be reporting the screen position of the upper left outer corner of the whole browser window. Firefox *also* supports "mozInnerScreenX" and "mozInnerScreenY" properties, and those work like you want - I don't know about other browsers.

Comment: You're a life-saver, changing the Y value to mozInnerScreen worked perfectly. The script broke completely in chrome and IE however, and even though I don't need it for them it would be nice if it'd be possible to set the script to use window.mozInnerScreenY if possible, else window.screenY if that doesn't work.

Comment: @user3163104 yes see [version 5 of that jsbin](http://jsbin.com/oDadOvo/5) :)  There may be an IE property like the Mozilla one, but I can't try IE at the moment.

Comment: @user3163104 one thing that's kind-of weird is that both Firefox and Chrome show the image with significantly different color than what the image looks like on my actual desktop background. Not wildly different, but it's quite noticeable.

Comment: Cheers man, you work fast.
The color of the background between firefox and my desktop is also ever so slightly off (IPS-panel, and not notecable unless you really look hard), but I'd imagine that's because of the different renderingengines/techniques used or something?

Anyway, thank you so much for your help, it works perfectly and looks great. My cap off to you, and have a good evening.

Comment: @Pointy So this solution has worked great for the last few years, but I've ran into a problem when it comes to positioning the background when using the wallpaper of a multi-monitor setup. This solution has the background-position set to the regular left top position, and when the primary monitor is placed on the right of any other monitors, this causes the background to be offset.Is it possible to combine the code with a background-position set to right center, and add an x offset of 3120px [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/oDadOvo/5)? I've tried to find a solution but been unable to.

Comment: @user3163104 wow mostly I'm impressed that there was a time when I actually knew how to do this :)  I mean I think I see what I was doing but I don't recall how I stumbled upon the solution or what I might have been doing that would have made it necessary for me to know!

Comment: @Pointy Ah, unfortunate - figured it was worth a try. And for the record I'm equally impressed. I'll try to find a solution to it and update the post if I come up with anything.

Comment: So just in case anyone were to stumble upon this later on, the problem got solved by simply adding a certain pixel offset rather than bothering with changing background-position.

Offset was added by changing previous code to:

-(sx = window[xp] - 2560) + 'px ' + -(sy = window[yp] + 278) + 'px';